# SwiftUI: reset state for .sheet(_: onDismiss:)

Tags: swift, state, swiftui

I've implemented a `onTapGesture` on a view that present another view using a `.sheet`.

When the user dismiss the sheet using the swipe down gesture, I'm changing my `@State` back to false. (with the `.sheet(_: onDismiss:)`)

First time I tap on a card, the sheet is presented.

However after dismissing the .sheet and tapping again on a `Card()`, the sheet isn't presented.

I'm not sure why it isn't working: I added 2 prints statement to check the value of the @State and it is set back to `false` when I dismiss the `.sheet`

```
struct CardView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var bixiModel: BixiStationCombinedListViewModel

    @State var isModalOpen: Bool = false

    var station: BixiStationCombinedViewModel

    var body: some View {

        ZStack(alignment: .leading){

            Card(station: station)

        }

        .onTapGesture {
            self.isModalOpen = true
            print(self.isModalOpen)

// Prints: true

        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$isModalOpen, onDismiss: {
            self.isModalOpen = false
            print(self.isModalOpen)

// Prints: false

            })
            {
                BixiStationDetailView(station: self.station)
                    .environmentObject(self.bixiModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why my implementation isn't working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heads up on this: with iOS 13.1 Beta 1, Xcode 11 Beta 7, it's been fixed!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you have the `.sheet` inside a `List`. If so then it's a known bug that hopefully gets fixed. In the interim you have to move `.sheet` out of the `List` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!